# Show that at one of these points the tangent to the curve is parallel to the $x$ axis

Tags: calculus, curves

Show that at one of these points $(4,18)$,$(4,-2)$  the tangent line to the curve $y^2-4xy-x^2=20$ is parallel to the $x$ axis.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am confused as to what the curve is : something involving $y^2-4xy-x^2$, ok. When I substitute $(4,18)$ and $(4,-2)$ in that I get different values. Is there an error?

Comment: Your curve is not defined. Did you mean $y^2-3xy-x^2=0$?

Comment: Maybe you should use MathJax to write the equation

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon i made a mistake i forgot the 20. sorry do you know how to solve it now. or any help.

Comment: @Aryan Hemmati i am so so sorry its =20

Comment: @maryjames Then you have answers below to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivate your curve like the following:
$\frac{d}{dx}(y^2-4xy-x^2)=2y(y')-2x-4x(y')-4y=\frac{dy}{dx}(20)=0$
$\implies y'=\frac{x+2y}{y+2x}$
So the tangent line in point $P=(x,y)$ is parallel to the x-axis $\iff y'=\frac{x+2y}{y+2x}=0 \iff x+2y=0 \iff x=-2y$ so the point $(4,-2)$ has the property.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Calculate the slope by differentiating the curve at both of these points. Slope of any tangent parallel to x-axis should be zero.